# How to read complex text file in c++?

Tags: c++, file-io, text-files

A text file I what to read has a certain pattern:

```
Name line [tag name 452,54 | tag2 name 323,2 | tag3 name 252,25 ... ]
Name2 line [tag name 422,54 | tag2 name 33,2 | tag3 name 111,525 | tag4 name 222,2 ... ]
```

The most troublesome part of dealing with this file is the number of *tags* per each line is not set.

I was trying to make it work by reading file line by line and exploding the lines into variables using `scanf()` because it seamed to be good at reading patterns. But `tag name` word count is not set, so it was not much of a help either.

I can manipulate file pattern a bit without losing any data to make it easier to read but no solution have crossed my mind.
Examples of how can I manipulate file pattern:

```
Name line 
tag name 452,54 | tag2 name 323,2 | tag3 name 252,25 ... 
Name2 line 
tag name 422,54 | tag2 name 33,2 | tag3 name 111,525 | tag4 name 222,2 ...
```

I added `[]` and `|` symbols as separators but ideally the less of them the better.

```
Name line 
tag name 452,54 
tag2 name 323,2
tag3 name 252,25 ... 
Name2 line 
tag name 422,54
tag2 name 33,2
tag3 name 111,525
tag4 name 222,2 ...
```

If you have read with similar patterns please share. I am a bit stuck now...

EDIT: It is a simple .txt  file and I chose `tags name` and `name line` as substitutes for any string value. There are no id or something else to make it easy.

Comment: What's the layout of the structure that you want this loaded into?  A standard indexed array or a hash?

Comment: You need to be more specific about your format. Is `line` a delimiter or part of the input? Also the file format seems a little broken. Why would there be a `tagN` when each `N` is defined by the position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mangling your file until you can read it, you should look closely at the grammar that defines your file format and build a small parser. While the task may look daunting at first, it is not that difficult.

I prefer [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/) for such tasks.

Comment: I agree with the idea but I am not allowed to use any external libraries, that is why I am struggling bad.

Comment: @Povylas: Then you should look into the tools Akshay mentions in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9382055/160206).

Comment: @Povylas The line between an external library and headers copied into your project is thin and only few student assistants that teach your project can see it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are searching for a *parser*. There are lots of them online. :) Even lex/yacc or bison or something can help out.

Comment: These are not parsers, but parser generators.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must write your own code and maintain newline to have the special meaning, of tag separation, you could use a combination of fgets() and strtok().
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/